# Derivative of $\ln |x|$ in the distributional sense

Tags: calculus, derivatives, distribution-theory

Consider the function $\ln |x|$, since it is locally integrable we can form the distribution

$$(\ln |x|,\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln |x|\phi(x)dx.$$

Now, I want to show that in the sense of distributions we have $\ln |x|' = \operatorname{Pv}\frac{1}{x}$. My obvious try was to substitute directly the definition of the derivative for distributions:

$$(\ln |x|', \phi)=-(\ln |x|,\phi')=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln |x|\phi'(x)dx,$$

the obvious thing to do would be to split this in two integrals:

$$(\ln |x|', \phi)=-\int_{-\infty}^0 \ln(-x)\phi'(x)dx - \int_0^\infty \ln (x) \phi'(x)dx.$$

Now, I've seem the question [Derivative of a distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123635/derivative-of-a-distribution) and it tells what to do next: we simply rewrite all of that as

$$(\ln |x|,\phi')=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\ln |x|\phi'(x)dx+\int_{\epsilon}^\infty \ln |x|\phi'(x)dx$$

But I can't understand where this limit comes from. I mean how does one get from where I stopped all the way to this line? Because obviously after that just inetgration by parts is enough to get what we want.

My doubt is how that $\epsilon \to 0^+$ really appeared.

Comment: Did you try to use integration by parts to switch the derivative back onto $\ln x$ and $\ln(-x)$? At least away from $0$, I'd expect your distributional derivative to coincide with the derivative $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: If we do this we get that the derivative in the sense of distributions in this case coincides with the usual derivative in the sense that $\ln' |x| = 1/x$ right? But what about the point zero? In the usual derivative it would not even make sense to ask, because $\ln |x|$ isn't defined there. But in the sense of distributions it doesn't matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivative of a distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123635/derivative-of-a-distribution)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that other question. I saw your answer there but there's a minor detail I didn't understand. Something I believe to be very basic. I added an edit here about it. My whole doubt is: if $(\ln |x|,\phi)$ is defined as $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\ln |x|\phi(x)dx$, why this suddenly turned into a principal value?

Comment: $\ln |x|$ is integrable on a neighborhood of $0$; $1/x$ is not.

Comment: Just differentiate directly and use chain rule: $$(\log |x|)'=\frac {\text{sign}(x)}{|x|}=\frac 1 x$$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $\ln(|x|)$ is $\text{Vp} \frac{1}{x}$:

$$\langle \ln(|x|)', \phi \rangle = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln(|x|) \phi'(x) dx$$

$$=- \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \ln(|x|) \phi'(x) dx $$

$$=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \underbrace{-\ln(|\epsilon|) (\phi(-\epsilon)-\phi(\epsilon))}_{\to 0} + \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{ \phi(x)}{x}   dx$$

$$=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{ \phi(x)}{x}   dx$$

Comment: Thanks for answering @Tryss. I understood almost all of the reasoning. The only thing that confuses me is: why do we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln(|x|) \phi'(x) dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \ln(|x|) \phi'(x) dx$$ I mean, I can't get where this limit comes from in this case. After all the integral was over the entire line. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1620696: It is a few years later, but maybe someone who comes to this question now in the future will have the same question. The reason this limit holds is because although the integral is over the entire line, the function $\phi(x)$ (and hence also its derivative $\phi'(x)$) is compactly supported, and of course $\ln(|x|)$ is a locally integrable function, and so the limit holds.

Answer (score 1):

To complete your computation, integrate by parts, using the fact that $\phi(x)-\phi(0)$ has the same derivative as $\phi(x)$. The result: $(\ln'|x|,\phi) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\phi(x)-\phi(0)\over x}\,dx$.